# VS2012 debug: cannot attach to process

Tags: wpf, debugging, visual-studio-2012

I have two WPF solutions:

Solution A

```
 Project A1 (XBAP/WPF Application)
 Project A2 (UserControl Library)
```

Solution B

```
 Project B1 (UserControl Library)
```

I reference A2.dll & B1.dll in A1.dll. I have both solution A & B opened in different VS2012 instances. When I debug A1.dll, I would like to debug A2.dll & B1.dll as well.

1. A2.dll could be debugged since i am in same solution as A1.dll.
2. For B1.dll, I use Debug->Attach to process-> A1.dll. But the breakpoints are not hit saying that no symbols have been loaded for this assembly.

Work around:

If I open the B1.dll file in Solution A, the break points are hit, but it is a painful process given the number of solutions and projects we have as application grows.

I verified that:

1. B1.pdb file is present and accessible to A1.dll.
2. In Solution A, Debug->Windows->Modules: I see B1.dll and it says
   that symbols have been loaded.
3. I do *not* have "Just My Code" checked.
4. I cleared my local box and got latest code from team server.
5. Rebooted my box.
6. Have no add-in installed except NuGet.

It used to work on my box and is still working for my team members, but suddenly stopped working for me. This is quite irritating and awfully time consuming.

Comment: Are you referencing a version of B1.dll that has been compiled for debugging (in the A solution)?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but there are no version issues for sure since I can debug B1.dll while debugging solution A by explicitly opening the files in solution A. Also, as I mentioned it used to work earlier.